# add time in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

| START_TIME | FROM | TO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 10:02 AM | 01-01-2021 10:00 AM | 01-01-2021 10:05 AM |
| 01-01-2021 10:07 AM | 01-01-2021 10:05 AM | 01-01-2021 10:10 AM |
| 02-01-2021 08:30 PM | 02-01-2021 08:30 PM | 02-01-2021 08:35 PM |

I have a table TIME_TABLE with start time. I want to add two more columns 'FROM' and 'TO' which stores 5 minutes interval of the start_time. I tried this but couldn't figure out a generic way in Oracle db.

Comment: Is it a Date or Timestamp?

Comment: @Rezu it's Date formatted to DD-MM-YYYY hh24:mi:ss

Comment: The AM is the new columns in the last row - that's a typo, right? The `START_TIME` is in the PM.

Comment: @mathguy yes so sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such data shouldn't be "stored" - that would be a flagrant violation of third normal form. Either create the columns as ***virtual*** columns (calculated on the fly whenever they are invoked), or create a view based on the table, with these two columns added - and then whenever you need the data from these columns, select from the view instead of the base table.

Either way, the computation is the same. You should only need the "from" column (the "to" is a trivial computation, adding five minutes to "from").

To compute the "from", take a date - **any** date, let's call it `dt` - and remember that in Oracle, "date" always means "date and time-of-day component". We will add the correct time-of-day to the date component of `dt` - the final formula for `from_date` will look something like

```
trunc(dt) + <something>
```

To find the "something", start with `dt - trunc(dt)`, which is the "time-of-day" component, expressed as a number of days. It is a number between 0 and 1, of course; for example, if the time-of-day is 9 AM, then this number is 9/24 = 0.375.

Take this number and convert it from days (between 0 and 1) to minutes (between 0 and 1440: there are 24 * 60 = 1440 minutes in a day). Divide the result by 5 (for full five-minute intervals) and truncate to the integer value. Add this many times "five minutes".

The final formula:

```
trunc(dt) + trunc( 1440 * (dt - trunc(dt)) / 5 ) * interval '5' minute
```

Note that 1440 / 5 can be simplified to 288, so you could also write

```
trunc(dt) + trunc( 288 * (dt - trunc(dt)) ) * interval '5' minute
```

Brief illustration:

```
select sysdate as start_date,
       trunc(sysdate) + trunc(288*(sysdate - trunc(sysdate))) 
                        * interval '5' minute as from_date
from   dual;

START_DATE          FROM_DATE          
------------------- -------------------
27-07-2021 11:09 PM 27-07-2021 11:05 PM
```

(I applied the computation to `sysdate` - you will apply it to your `start_date` column.)